# Rotating a cube so that the front facing face remains square

Tags: c++, c, opengl, 3d, transformation

In OpenGL I have to rotate a cube (and translate it) so that it looks like in these two images. [image: cubes]

Without any transformations only the front facing red face is visible. I just don't understand how I can rotate it (so that the top and right sides are visible like in the images) and keep the red face perfectly square.

I've thought about translating it to the bottom left, but that only moves the red square around, it doesn't make the other faces visible.

I'm using `glFrustum(-20, 20, -20, 20, -1, -10);`

Comment: "it doesn't make the other faces visible." -> use a perspective projection then, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a perspective projection (which you are) and the front face of your cube is parallel to the x-y plane, then you will only see the other two faces if the cube is entirely in one quadrant of the eye space; that is, if there were horizontal and vertical lines cutting the window in half, the cube would have to lie entirely within one of the four resulting rectangles.

Other options for making the other two faces show are

- use an isometric projection
- rotate the cube to bring the other faces into view.

To aid in visualising this, try playing [Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/) (say) and moving around in different ways to see how different sides of different blocks come into view.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a rotation.

The second picture looks like an orthographic projection (`glOrtho`), but that may be a coincidence.

In either case, you can only get an image like that if the cube is *translated* away from the origin toward the bottom left, as you suggest.

Comment: +1 : it's a translation. But the second pic is not a ortho projection. It's a cavalier projection.